# How do I set the style of a column in a table with a command that takes an argument?

Tags: tables

I wish to have a column of my table in IPA style, so that the result is like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
1 & \textipa{w2n} \\
2 & \textipa{tu:} \\
3 & \textipa{Tri:}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I know there are ways to format an entire column of a table. I've tried looking into the array package, but using `{c|>{\textipa}c}` doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [`collcell`](//ctan.org/pkg/collcell) was built for - to `coll`ect the contents of a `cell` and pass it as an argument to some macro. You use a similar format suggested by [`array`](//ctan.org/pkg/array) to insert the start and end clause for the column: `>{\collectcell<cmd>}<col spec><{\endcollectcell}`

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tipa,collcell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c | c >{\collectcell\textipa}c<{\endcollectcell} }
  1 & \textipa{w2n}  & w2n  \\
  2 & \textipa{tu:}  & tu:  \\
  3 & \textipa{Tri:} & Tri:
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```